# AngularJS - how to repeat every 2 items in a list with ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am using AngularJS 1.5.3

I have a list of items that I want to display in my view.
Every 2 items I want to show a new div underneath the first one.

```
  <div class="col text-center" ng-repeat="event in weekDay.events">
    &nbsp;<small>{{ event.times }}</small>
  </div>
```

For example, this is the result I want to see:
[image]

I am not sure how I can do this with ng-repeat.

Comment: you could've at least rotate the image..jesus..

Comment: @ZombieChowder maybe that's exactly how he wants it: text going upwards and rows are now columns

Comment: @AlekseySolovey surely...

Comment: No, sorry the image should be rotated.

Comment: @user1261710: please check my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you have bootstrap to do it ?

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6 text-center" ng-repeat="event in weekDay.events">
    &nbsp;<small>{{ event.times }}</small>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well I am using ionic 1.3.5

Comment: @VickyGonsalves if instead of text I would have images in there, they will overlap each other (per row), what do I add to keep them separate?

Comment: @AlekseySolovey Make the images responsive with respect to divs. Note that OPs question is related to DOM structure. He did not mention specifically how he wants to play with the array.

Comment: @VickyGonsalves indeed `class="img-responsive"` works well, I had a hack with `width="100%"` before, but small images would be stretched if not for `col-xs-6` restriction

Answer (score 0):

You can use **$index** to get the index of current item in your ng-repeat loop. Then you can check if the current $index is **odd** if so then your can display your div.
Your code should look like this:

```
<div class="col text-center" ng-repeat="event in weekDay.events">
    &nbsp;<small>{{ event.times }}</small>
    <div class="my-new-div" ng-if="$index%2==1">
       <span>My div stuffs</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think there is a built-in version `ng-if="$odd"` (or `$even`)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with other answers that say it is simpler to use css to place 2 items in each row, but if you don't want to do that you can try the following

get number of items in your events divided by number of items you want to display in each row (in this case 2)

```
  $scope.getNumber = function() {
    console.log($scope.data.length / 2)
    if($scope.data.length % 2 == 0)
      return new Array($scope.data.length / 2);
    else
      return new Array(Math.floor($scope.data.length/2) + 1);   
  }
```

and modify your ng-repeat to display current and next item in each iteration

```
<div ng-repeat="item in getNumber() track by $index">
    <span>{{data[$index * 2]}}</span> &nbsp;&nbsp;
    <span>{{data[$index * 2 + 1]}}</span>
</div>
```

[**Demo**](https://plnkr.co/edit/cYHRw7YNCDfSbFJnJb6l?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Use this below code. it will work

```
<div class="col text-center" ng-repeat="event in weekDay.events">
        <div ng-show="$index%2==0">
            &nbsp;<small>{{ event.times }}</small>
            &nbsp;<small>{{ weekDay.events[$index+1].times }}</small>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Please check this below small working example.

```
!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
<div ng-repeat="event in weekDay.events" style="border:1px solid black">
    <div ng-show="$index%2==0">
        {{event.times}}
        {{weekDay.events[$index+1].times}}
    </div>

</div>

<script src="../lib/angular.js"></script>
<script>
    var app = angular.module('app', []);
    app.controller('ctrl', function ($scope) {

        $scope.weekDay = {
            "events": [
                { "times": "one", "day": "1" },
                { "times": "two", "day": "2" },
                { "times": "three", "day": "3" },
                { "times": "four", "day": "4" },
                { "times": "five", "day": "5" },
                { "times": "six", "day": "6" },
                { "times": "seven", "day": "7" },
                { "times": "eight", "day": "8" },
            ]
        };

    });
</script>
```